# Zeebus Puzzle #7

Tags: word, rebus

[image]

Time for another rebus puzzle...break a leg!

Hint #1:

> There's something those numbers have in common...

Hint #2:

> No math required...

Hint #3:

> Turn on your TV (or Netflix or Hulu) to see the winners...

Comment: "*Time* for another rebus..." was that a deliberate pun? :D

Comment: You're on the right track ;)

Comment: And also, Rot13(Gur jbeq "gvzr" raqf jvgu ZR)... hmmm... :P

Comment: Wild guess - ENEMY?

Comment: Oh I think I got it!! @zeethreepio ...fingers crossed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could this be

> Primetime Emmy? (Prime Time+M+E)

Note that

> 7, 59, and 11 are all prime numbers, which makes them prime times!

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer (yet), but for some reason I think that it is somehow linked to

> Sum of all natural numbers. 7:59-11:11 gives -4:48 as a result. If you see it as a fraction, then you can simplify it to -1/12, which is also a [sum of all natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF).

Still looking for a solution, but maybe this part can help somebody smarter than me? :)

Comment: This is a very interesting coincidence. The answer is definitely less complex but +1 for finding this connection!

Comment: Is it really the sum of all natural numbers? Only in a paradoxical dimension of numbers... $(+1)$ :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking a guess with this:

> I'm behind the times

Oh wait! Got a better one - I think it's actually:

> The odds are against me - because all the numbers are odd.